# javascript ajax changes the variable that django sends from views

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, jinja2

For strange reasons the value of a variable that I am sending from django to html gets changed in javascript ajax.

I am sending `id` from `views.py` and then in body I use `{{ id }}` and it is equal to the value that it was in `views.py`.

But when in `<script>` I use `var id = {{ id }};` I get a different value: the new value is slightly different than the original value.

original value          = 9211775239375291 

value in javascript = 9211775239375292

What am i doing wrong here?

In views.py:

```
context = {
    'id' : str(id)
}

return detail_page(request,context)
```

In .html :

```
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">

var myVar = setInterval(ReLoad , 5000);

var id = {{ id }};

function ReLoad() {
   var url = '/data/' + id;
  $.get( url, function(data) {
    var result = JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
    console.log( JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'))['code'] );
    document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = result['code'];
  })
  .fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) {
    console.log('error', status, error)
  });
}

</script>
<head>


<body>

{{ id }}

<div class="w3-container" id="code"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: What is "slightly different"? Can you give examples of the original value and what ends up in your JS.

Comment: original value       =  9211775239375291                                                        value in javascript=  9211775239375292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, JS rounding interferes. Make sure to use the variable as a JS string:

```
var id = "{{ id }}";
```